# Excel, select date and amount from table that match category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet that lists expenses.
The columns are Date, Category, Amount, Description, Sub Category, and Subscription.
I want to return a list of the date and, amount of all records with the category "Investment", on to different worksheets called Budget from a worksheet called Expenses.

In SQL you would write it as
`SELECT Date, Category FROM Expenses WHERE Category == "Investment";`
But I'm using excel and not good at execl.

The Expense worksheet has a title on the first row, column names on the second row, data starting on the third row, and columns going A to F, in the order first stated above.

Is there a way to display the results onto another worksheet using excel functions?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the SUMIF function. Read all about it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b, or maybe a pivot table https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576. One of the two for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have office 365, all you got to do is, goto the Budget sheet and type in the formula

```
=FILTER(Expenses!A2:F33,Expenses!B2:B33="Investment")
```

Where range A2:F33 and B2:B33 is the total array in Expenses sheet that needs to be adjusted to your data